# C++ polymorphism, about announcing a basis class reference to a derived class

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A {
private:
    int nVal;
public:
    void Fun()
    {
        cout << "A::Fun" << endl;
    }
    void Do()
    {
        cout << "A::Do" << endl;
    }
};
class B :public A {
public:
    virtual void Do()
    {
        cout << "B::Do" << endl;
    }
};
class C :public B {
public:
    void Do()
    {
        cout << "C::Do" << endl;
    }
    void Fun()
    {
        cout << "C::Fun" << endl;
    }
};
void Call(B& p)

{
    p.Fun(); p.Do();
}
int main() {
    C c; Call(c);
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, the output is

```
A::Fun

C::Do
```

But I cannot understand. in the function call(B& p), the reference p should refer to c from C class, so why the output is not

```
C::Fun

C::Do
```

When announcing a a basis class reference to a derived class, is the different basis class making any sense?

Comment: You need to make the functions virtual in the base class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `A::Fun` is not marked as `virtual`, therefore it doesn't find `C::Fun` at run-time. You should mark it as such:

```
class A {
private:
    int nVal;
public:
    virtual void Fun()
    {
        cout << "A::Fun" << endl;
    }
// ...
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/HjIvTK9NAs9HXowf)

---

This is a great example of an error that could be caught at compile-time thanks to the [**`override` specifier**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override):

```
class C :public B {
public:
    void Do() override
    {
        cout << "C::Do" << endl;
    }
    void Fun() override
    {
        cout << "C::Fun" << endl;
    }
};
```

Would print:

```
error: 'void C::Fun()' marked 'override', but does not override
     void Fun() override
          ^~~
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/VUgtq99zQNtJcRY7)

Comment: Thank you! I found I did not truly understand class reference before. When do "B& p", this will first look into B and then look into A and found that A has fun() but it is not virtual. So it directly calls fun() of A. Is that right?